# cypress scripts are failing in circleci with the error "Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying..."

Tags: circleci, cypress

I am getting an error in circle ci "Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying..." while running a cypress script. So each script needs to visit a webpage. Apparently the first two script are connecting to the chrome browser but the third script onwards I am getting the error

### Script that is failing

```
describe('Visual regression for elements in homepage', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
            cy.viewport("macbook-15")
            })
            it('Take the screenshots of the entire Homepage of Thequint beta env', () => {       
            cy.visit('/elections')
            cy.get('sa[href="/"][data-reactid="7"]').click()
            cy.get("#container").matchImageSnapshot('Homepage',{coverage: "fullpage"})
            })
            it('Take the screenshots of the entire Homepage of Thequint beta env', () => {   
            cy.visit(Cypress.env("thequintbeta"))
            cy.get("#container").matchImageSnapshot('Homepage',{coverage: "fullpage2"})
            })
            })
```

So the cypress should be able to connect to browser headlessly but it is not able to connect . [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC4Qv.png)

Comment: I believe the web page is inaccessible in the test environment? Can you try doing a ping through `wget/ curl`, which may help you to debug further.

Comment: I Have a couple of spec files that I am running in the job, the first two spec files are running fine, Browser starts timing out from the third spec fine onwards

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3310 My issue matches with this issue

Comment: Would suggest you to add more debug logs. You may follow the instructions here - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Print-DEBUG-logs